# is it possible to Use Kafka with Google cloud Dataflow

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

i have two question

1) I want to use Kafka with Google cloud Dataflow Pipeline program. in my pipeline program I want to read data from kafka is it possible?

2) I created Instance with BigQuery enabled now i want to enable Pubsub how can i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Ad mentioned by Raghu, support for writing to/reading from Kafka was added to Apache Beam in mid-2016 with the `KafkaIO` package. You can check the [package's documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html)[1] to see how to use it.

(2) I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you provide more details?

[1] https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html

Comment: In instances property under Permissions, 
i had following options .
User info    Disabled
Compute      Disabled
Storage   Read Only
Task queue   Disabled
BigQuery     Disabled
Cloud SQL    Disabled
Cloud Datastore Disabled
Cloud Logging   Write Only
Cloud Platform  Disabled .. 
so i guessed i have to ennable Pub/Sub while the creation itself, but i was wrong.

Comment: When is the future? I'd love to use Kafka as part of a Dataflow pipeline.

Comment: You can now use the Apache Beam SDK with the Cloud Dataflow service, and it includes transforms for reading and writing with Kafka: https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/kafka

Answer (score 2):

Kafka support was added to Dataflow (and Apache Beam) in mid 2016. You can read and write to Kafka streaming pipelines. See JavaDoc for `KafkaIO` in Apache Beam.

Answer (score 1):

(2) As of April 27, 2015, you can enable Cloud Pub/Sub API as follows:

1. Go to your project page on the Developer Console
2. Click `APIs & auth` -> `APIs`
3. Click `More` within `Google Cloud APIs`
4. Click `Cloud Pub/Sub API`
5. Click `Enable API`

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got it. and enabled Cloud Pub/Sub API.