# Is it possible to consume from an Azure EventHub topic using Apache Beam / Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, azure-eventhub, streaming-analytics

**Problem**

We'd like to consume from an EventHub topic in Azure using a dataflow pipeline in Google Cloud.

**Question**

Is it known whether KafkaIO allows for consuming from EventHubs directly in an Apache Beam/Google Cloud dataflow job? (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080893/kafka-to-google-cloud-platform-dataflow-ingestion))

Alternative approaches for getting the EventHub data into Pub/Sub are also appreciated (e.g. Publish from Azure Streaming Analytics to Pub/Sub)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Event Hubs supports the [Apache Kafka protocol 1.0 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview), so you should be able to consume events from Event Hubs using [KafkaIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.17.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html) (which supports Kafka versions 0.10.1 and newer). Google Cloud has a guide for processing messages from Kafka in Dataflow [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/processing-messages-from-kafka-hosted-outside-gcp).

Answer (score 1):

Azure Event Hubs is binary compliant with Kafka protocol so any Kafka client or pipeline should be able to consume events from an Event Hubs topic.