# how to integrate events from Azure Events Hub (kafka interface) to google cloud pub/sub

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement where I need to consume a kafka topic on Azure events hub. POST endpoint needs to be created which will consume a topic provided as an argument. The message has to be send on a pubsub topic with the kafka topic as attribute and the message content as body.

This is a high level requirement. I have looked [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector) to understand how this can be achieved. However, if anyone has implemented this in real time that is events from Azure events hub to google cloud pub sub or have worked on similar implementation, please help.

Comment: In order to understand the overview of your process, could you tell me what is the final data destination? After Pub/Sub receiving the message, what will you do ? Also, have you checked this [tutorial](https://qwiklabs.medium.com/integrate-kafka-with-google-cloud-pub-sub-96084d3bd2b7)?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, thank you for lookin into it. From pub/sub it will go to Big query. At this point we are not sure if its going to be via data flow or GKE to big query.

Comment: Since your data's destination is BigQuery have you considered using the [Kafka to BigQuery template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#running-the-apache-kafka-to-bigquery-template) in Dataflow? Or even building a template to be used by Dataflow to read directly from Kafka using the [KafkaIO method](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.Read.html) ? Check this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kafka-to-bigquery-using-dataflow-6ec73ec249bb) for more details. Would that attend your needs ?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, Thank you for your inputs. I will look into this and let you know. There are specific requirements so need to understand if we can do Kafka to bigquery . I am new to this and hence would you please explain me in what scenarios we could go with kafka -> Pub sub-> Big query and not directly like kafka to big query? Appreciate your help here.

Comment: If you go to the GCP Console > Dataflow > Create job from template > Open tutorial, then an explanation of the requirements to use this template will appear. Basically, the bigquery Table and kafka topic should exist already and the messages should be in a valid JSON format. You provide the info about your Kafka topic (name and bootstrap server list) and run the job.

Comment: About ***Kafka>PubSub>BigQuery***, you can write your own pipeline using [KafkaIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html) to read from the Kafka topic and then write it to BigQuery such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080893/kafka-to-google-cloud-platform-dataflow-ingestion). You could try any of these two options and post another question in case you find any issues. Did this information help you?  If yes, I will summarise it in an answer so it further contributes to the community.

Comment: hello @AlexandreMoraes, this helps to start with. Thanks much. I shall look into the details and post other questions if I have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section, in order to further contribuite to the community, I am posting the summary of our discussion as an answer.

Since your data's destination is BigQuery, you can use the [Kafka to BigQuery template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#running-the-apache-kafka-to-bigquery-template) in Dataflow, you can use this template to load json messages from Kafka to BigQuery. In addition, according to the documentation,

> **How to use this Dataflow template**
> Kafka to BigQuery
> This template creates a streaming pipeline that ingests JSON data from Kafka, executes an optional JavaScript user defined function (UDF), and writes the resulting records to BigQuery. Any errors during the transformation of the data, execution of the UDF, or writing into BigQuery will be written into a separate errors table in BigQuery. The errors table will be created if it does not exist.

> **Pipeline Requirements**
>
> - The Kafka topic(s) exists and the message is encoded as a valid JSON.
> - The BigQuery output table exists.
> - The Kafka brokers are reachable from the Dataflow worker machines.

On the other hand, you can create your own template with your specific requirements using the [KafkaIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.Read.html) method, you can check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kafka-to-bigquery-using-dataflow-6ec73ec249bb) to understand better how to start with.